# Neo4j - extracting nodes based on property

Tags: scala, neo4j

Suppose there are employee nodes with salary as one of the properties. What is the fastest way of getting the employee nodes whose salaries are in top 5 using Scala-Neo4j Api?

Answer (score 3):

You could index employees with their salaries as a property.
In this case, you just have to get the index and then query on his members. In Java it looks like :

```
db.index().forNodes('salaries').query(YOURQUERY)
```

You could either use labels (if your use Neo4j 2) to tag nodes as employees and search only in those nodes.

You could also set a type property on each of your employee set on "employee" to search across all the nodes (but it will take time if you've got many nodes)

Another solution is to create a relationship is_a between employees and a super-node "employe" but it could, depending of your usage, cause troubles (see http://www.aleksavukotic.com/2011/07/neo4j-super-nodes-and-indexed.html).

These are a few different ways to search. Some are faster in certain case, you have to tune it according to your needs.
If you're talking about the query you have to make to search, the documentation on Cypher and the Javadoc should be helpful.

Comment: what should be my query in this case?

Comment: What case ? (those parenthesis are useless but I have to type a certain amount of chars to add my comment)